# nopCommerce change Quantity and StockQuantity to Double or Float

Tags: nopcommerce

I’m using nopCommerce2.5 and I have searched far and wide for someone who has updated the “add to cart quantity” and “StockQuantity” to a Decimal or Float.

I need a minimum of .25 in stock and then be able to increment by .25…

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just jump in and change all references to Quantity throughout the entire solution and it all works fine.